# Implementing Applicative#traverse

Tags: scala

[Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) defines `Applicative#traverse` as:

```
def traverse[A,B](as: List[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[List[B]]
    as.foldRight(unit(List[B]()))((a, fbs) => map2(f(a), fbs)(_ :: _))
```

However, I implemented this function as:

```
  def traverse[A,B](as: List[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[List[B]] =
    as.foldRight(unit(List[B]()))((elem, acc) => map2(acc, f(elem))(_ :+ _))
```

With `unit` and `map2` defined as:

```
  def map2[A,B,C](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])(f: (A,B) => C): F[C]
  def unit[A](a: => A): F[A]
```

As I understand my implementation, the `map2(acc, f(elem))(_ :+ _))` will behave as so:

> for each (element, accumulator), call map2(acc, f(elem)(_ :+ _)) 
>   to append the result of f(elem) (type F[B]) to the accumulator (type F[List[B]])

For my implementation, then, in the `(f: (A,B) => C)` part of `traverse`'s `map2` calls, `List[B]` appends `B` to itself.

`map2` accepts arguments `F[A]` and `F[B]`, but the function argument `f` operates on the `A` and `B` types. In the FP in Scala solution, `B` gets added to `List[B]` via the `::` operator.

Is that right?

Comment: I can follow most of what you say, but I have no idea what do you mean by "Is that right"? Is it that what you said is correct, that your implementation is correct, or what?

Comment: All of the above, please :), Sensei. Since my answer is similar to the official answer, but the only difference appears to be that I'm `appending`, rather than `prepending` each element to the `accumulator`.

Comment: Well, you get the elements in the reverse order from the official answer, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding of what is going on. Note, however, that your implementation will produce a list in the reverse order of what is expected, so if you used the identity monad as `F`, you'd get back a reversed list, instead of the same list.